# Under what circumstance is one justified in ruling a [usb flash, thumb drive] to be dead?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

What should be the criteria for declaring a usb thumb drive non-functional/faulty? I'm talking specifically about the typically inexpensive (though sometimes more expensive) USB storage devices. Should it be "Windows asks you to format it when you insert it", or ...

Some might answer this question by taking the criteria drive-device manufacturers ask be filled before they warranty a replacement, although this might be a less strict definition of "dead". A definite and I think good answer to this question would be more in the form of "It is dead when it is no longer reparable by software, and that happens when **x** is the case." What is x?

Comment: When you've spent more time trying to revive it that it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

A USB drive should be declared "dead" when either the drive's physical connection has failed (e.g. a broken connection on the plug) or when the device can no longer be consistently read from and written to without errors (e.g. failing flash media).

Be aware that a drive can be "dead" ("no longer reparable by software") and then repaired by hand.  For instance, if I own a flash drive and manage to snap off the USB plug from overuse, I can solder it back together if the only damage is to the connection (not to the PCB inside the drive).

Comment: Remember, however, that the definition of "dead" can get fuzzy depending on who you are talking to.